# Looking at Visual Studio project is it possible to say it is model first or database first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I am going through an old project code in visual studio 2013. And wondering if there is a way I can definitely say whether this project is "Model First" or "Database first"?

Please refer below picture (not sure what else to provide):

[image]

Update:

I appears I did not clarify what I wanted to establish. I make another attempt. Basically as I understand when you add a new model using "Entity Data Model Wizard", you can choose Database First ("EF designer from database") or Model First ("Empty EF designer model"). At this time, we know whether we created database first or model first BUT

> Is it possible to tell looking at an existing code base?

I did as suggested by Tieson T. and choose "Empty EF Designer model" and click Finish. I got a Model1.edmx file. I am assuming what I did was a Model First approach. So I still have a .edmx file which is there in my existing project (which in answer he suggest is a database first approach). I followed this link msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj205424.aspx.

It may not be an important question but I am asking out of curiosity.

**Update 2:**

I did created two models using both approaches and this is what it looks in VS:

[image]

I noticed a .sql file I generated from model. Is it an indication?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `.edmx` files are only used by the database-first template. You can test this by generating one of each of the available templates.

You can also read the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399249%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The Entity Data Model Tools are designed to help you build Entity Framework applications. With the Entity Data Model Tools you can create a conceptual model from an existing database and then graphically visualize and edit your conceptual model. [...] The tools generate or modify an .edmx file, which contains information that describes the conceptual model, the storage model, and the mappings between them.

Comment: Thanks, I did as suggested but choose "Empty EF Designer model" and click Finish. I got a Model1.edmx file. I am assuming what I did was a Model First approach, right? Basically this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj205424.aspx